# Exclude some fields from being validated in $valid in AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, validation, angularjs-scope

I have two select boxes in which a user can move items from select box to another.
Say I have **SelectBox1** and **SelectBox2**.
I move all the available options from SelectBox1 to SelectBox2.
Now while submitting the form I am checking whether the form is valid or not.
But when I move all the options from SelectBox1 to SelectBox2, it sets the **$valid** flag to false, which prevents me from moving forward.
Is there a way to exclude selectBox1 from being validated by **$valid** in angularJS?

```
<select multiple="multiple" id="selectBox1" class="form-control" ng-model="available"  ng-options="role as role.Name for role in availableRoles"> </select>

<select multiple="multiple" id="selectBox2" class="form-control" required onchange="GetFunctionWisePrivileges()" ng-model="selected" ng-options="role as role.Name for role in selectedRoles"></select>
```

Also note that SelectBox1 is not required while SelectBox2 is required.

Comment: Fiddle will help us identify the issue..

Answer (score 0):

You could use `ng-disabled` and base it on the array length

```
<select ng-model="available"  ng-options="...." ng-disabled="!availableRoles.length"> </select>
```